# Adobe reader not initializing

Tags: 13.10, pdf, adobe

Adobe reader stopped working. There is no response when I start adobe reader using GUI. This is the error I get when I type `acroread` into the terminal:

```
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can I get any help? I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install `lib32stdc++6` from software center.
2. Remove previous `libstdc++.so.6` using `sudo rm /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libstdc++.so.6`
3. Make link using `sudo ln -s /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libstdc++.so.6`

Then `acroread` might work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `libstdc++6`. That's a shared library that `acroread` needs.

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.`this is what I got.

Comment: Can you please add the output of this command? `strace -e open /usr/bin/acroread 2>&1 | grep libstdc`, so we will find where acroread looks for the `libstdc` library and then you can make a link.

Comment: The output of above command is [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6367019/).

Comment: So you can see `acroread` tries some different location to open `libstdc` but it gets always -1 (file not found). Type `ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libstdc++.so.6` to create a link. Then acroread should find this library. Let me know if it works. If it does not work search for the libstdc++.so.6 library and paste the output of `find / -name "*libstdc++.so.6*"`

Comment: linking didn't worked. I think may be because of permissions. The linked `libstdc++` has owner as root.found `libstdc++.so.6` at `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Try installling `ia32-libs` with `apt-get install ia32-libs`. Just to make sure, please post the output of the following commands: `uname -a`, `grep flags /proc/cpuinfo`, `ldd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread`.

Comment: `ia32-libs` not getting installed.The output of mentioned commands is [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6369230/).

Comment: The commands look good, expect the install command. You have to install `ia32-libs`, that's the solution. But your repositories don't include the sources. I will find out the source when you post the ubuntu version `cat /etc/os-release`.

Comment: Last one, type: `echo "foreign-architecture i386" >/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` then `apt-get update` and then again `apt-get install ia32-libs`. Now it really should work xD

Comment: Sorry, even that didn't worked. How about unistalling adobe and installing again?

Comment: You can try, but it's the `ia32-libs` package you need to install somehow. Then adobe reader works. What was the output of those commands?

Comment: What is `ia32-libs` and what is the reason for such an abnormal behavior of adobe.The output was same as previous.

Comment: `ia32-libs` are the 32bit libraries that 32bit applications need to execute on a 64bit system. acroread is a 32bit application, I use it myself an a 64bit system. You also can try `apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`, this is the more direct way, but I don't think it will work...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11379/discussion-between-rajashekar007-and-chaos)

Answer (score 0):

Install some missing 32-bit dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns* libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```